# Express js is not serving static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to express js.I think this is a newbie problem.express js is not serving static files

```
var express = require('express');
express()
    .set('view engine','ejs')
    .use(express.static('public'))
    .get('/',function(req,res){
      res.render('index');
    })
    .listen(3000);
```

[image: Error]
[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use:

```
.use('/public', express.static('public'))
```

The first `public` is what you use as a prefix in your url. The second `public` is your physical folder in your file system.

Another option would be not to use `/public/*` in your urls.

From the docs:

> To create a virtual path prefix (where the path does not actually exist in the file system) for files that are served by the express.static function, specify a mount path for the static directory, as shown below:
>
> `app.use('/static', express.static('public'));`
>
> Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory from the /static path prefix.